# running validation on form array

Tags: php, forms, validation

I have a form which is dynamically built from an xml file and looks like this with all the meaningless info stripped out:

```
foreach($xml->config->popup as $popup_item)
{

  <label for="fm-popup_name[]">* Popup Name:</label>
  <input id="fm-popup_name[]" name="fm-popup_name[]" type="text"  value="<?php echo $popup_name ; ?>" />
  <label class="fm-req" for="fm-popup_desc[]">* Popup Description:</label>
  <textarea rows="4" cols="50" id="fm-popup_desc[]" name="fm-popup_desc[]" /></textarea>

  <label for="fm-popup_image[]">* Popup Image:</label>
  <input id="fm-popup_image[]" name="fm-popup_image[]" type="file" />
}
```

Now i have a validation script i use for client side

```
function validate()
{

if(document.getElementById('fm-popup_desc').value == "" || document.getElementById('fm-popup_desc').length < 4 || document.getElementById('fm-popup_desc').value > 30){
 alert( "The Description should be between 4 and 65,000 characters" );
 document.getElementById('fm-popup_desc').focus() ;
 return false;
}

var image_value = document.getElementById("fm-popup_image").value;
var ext_image = image_value.substring(image_value.lastIndexOf('.') + 1);

if(ext_image != "gif" && ext_image != "GIF" && ext_image != "JPEG" && ext_image != "jpeg" && ext_image != "jpg" && ext_image != "JPG" && ext_image != "png" && ext_image != "bmp"){
alert("Invalid image type, please try again using one of the following formats: gif, jpg, jpeg, bmp or png");
return false;
}

return(true);

}
```

Then i run the following on the form:

```
onSubmit="return validate()
```

Now that works fine for a static form but on my dynamic form im not sure how to make it run the validation for every loop.

I have a similar situation for my server side validation and i use the following to access each one for the file size and type validation:

```
$file_size = $_FILES[$form_field_name]['size'][$key];
```

But im not sure how to do a similar thing for the javascript as the current script runs onSubmit and im not sure how to access each value client side.

Comment: ids have to be unique. You can't run `getElementById('fm-popup_desc')` if there are multiple items with that id.

Comment: ok would running the function client side as onBlur() for each field so it would be run when the user attaches the image and then also do full validation server side be sufficient. By the way empty field for images are allowed but if they attach something then it must be a valid image type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you want you IDs to be unique. Assuming $popup_item is a good varname string:

```
foreach($xml->config->popup as $popup_item)
{
<input id="<?php echo $popup_name ; ?>" name="<?php echo $popup_name ; ?>" type="text"  value="" />
```

etc.

But then do another loop to generate your validation code:

```
foreach($xml->config->popup as $popup_item)
{
var image_value = document.getElementById("<?php echo $popup_name ; ?>").value;
```

etc.